# HTML Prints with different spacing depending on operating system

Tags: html, spacing, printing-web-page

I have an odd problem where an html table will print different on different operating systems.

The document being printed is within an IFrame and contains a table.  On windows xp and below everything works fine.

On windows 7, the table prints with a bunch of extra space between rows and widths of everything seem bigger.

Anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Do you mean that you're working on IE??

Comment: @MujtabaFathel Nope. Same experience in IE, Chrome, Firefox

Comment: The document within the iFrame is being displayed differently? What kind of document is being displayed.

Comment: @Zeb I believe it is a blank html page with a table on it. It is created by a legacy application and right click is disabled so it is hard for me to tell. I will dig into it

Comment: I was unsure if you were saying there was a document and a table or if the document contained the table. Unfortunately, that sounds like he creation of the document might be where the easiest fix is.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-browser/OS printing differences drove us to use PrinceXML (although  wkhtmltopdf can also work) on the server to render the HTML to PDF using print-specific CSS. Then when the user clicks print, we give them the PDF instead of rendering the page in the browser.

We get consistent results, regardless of what browser, operating system or device the user is on. This works for mobile print too.